# How to add headers and responseType in angular eventSource

Tags: angular, server-sent-events

I am working on one API/SSE where I get data in streams from backend. To recieve that on front end I am using eventSource. Its code is as below -

```js
let source = new EventSource("url", {headers, responseType: 'text'});
source.addEventListener('message', message => {
    let n: Notification;
    n = JSON.parse(message.data);
    console.log(message.data);
});
```

But what error I am facing is -

```
Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventSourceInit'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'headers' does not exist in type 'EventSourceInit'.
```

How can I add headers and responseType in eventSource?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can't add it. `EventSource()` itself does not accept such params (like the error message said too). What is the end-result you are looking for?

If you are trying to get the credentials, you could try this:

```js
let source = new EventSource("url", { withCredentials: true } );
```

All possible params and methods of the API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for quick response. I am trying to get the id. Also, im not understanding why this API is not adding Authorization header in it.

Comment: Again, what are you trying to achieve here? Once the connection is opened, incoming messages from the server are delivered to your code in the form of events. I.e with `EventSource` you can only listen to messages, but not post. If you want to POST some data to the server you could use httpClient to post over http. https://angular.io/guide/http